# How to plot a time series from BigQuery with a minute accuracy?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have a dataset in BigQuery, and I am using it as a source to create a report on Data Studio.

I can plot the data as a time series / combo / line chart using the Timestamp as dimension and other numeric fields I have as metrics.

The issue I have is that the most I can get as accuracy is down to the hour, while I need a minute accuracy. The dataset in BigQuery has an accuracy of milliseconds, but I don't seem to be able to get it in Data Studio.

I have read short suggestions about creating a string with the date and using that as metric, or extracting and combining a minute field, but I can't seem to be able to make it work.

[image: samp]

Comment: Can you post a link to a sample piece of CSV data that describes your data?  Obviously don't expose sensitive data but a sample of the data you are working with would be useful to examine what we are working with.

Comment: @Kolban I edited the question to include a sample of BigQuery's data.

Comment: This link may help .... https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Data-Studio/Can-t-create-a-minute-chart/td-p/1763571

Comment: It boggles the mind that this is something difficult to do in DataStudio. Just so you have no doubts -> "In Data Studio, metrics values are always aggregated". Congrats to the product team there for building a data vis tool that can't plot a plain old timeseries...  (ref:https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6402048?hl=en)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update 2019: minute resolution is now natively supported!

---

In BigQuery, `TRUNCATE` by `MINUTE` and `GROUP BY` it. Then in Data Studio set this timestamp as `STRING` value instead of a `DATE`. Create a line chart with this timestamp `STRING` as the `X` dimension, and voila.

[image]
[image]

Query for this vis:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT bus, ST_GeogPoint(longitude, latitude) point
    , PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d %H%M%S',FORMAT('%i %06d', day, time)) ts
  FROM `fh-bigquery.mta_nyc_si.201410_bustime`
  WHERE day=20141014
  AND bus IN (7043, 7086, 7076, 2421, 7052, 7071)
)

SELECT bus, TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(ts, MINUTE) ts, AVG(distance/time) speed
FROM (
  SELECT bus, ts
    , ST_DISTANCE(point, LAG(point, 3) OVER(PARTITION BY bus ORDER BY ts)) distance
    , TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ts, LAG(ts, 3) OVER(PARTITION BY bus ORDER BY ts), SECOND) time
  FROM data
)
WHERE time IS NOT null 
GROUP BY bus, ts
HAVING speed < 500
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view of you table using this query:

```
SELECT
  t.*,
  FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", t.timestamp) as date_time
FROM
  `project-id.dataset-id.table-id` AS t
```

After creating such view, you can add this view as your data source and use the field `date_time` for your time series